# Use string as mathematical expression in C

Tags: c, string

I want to know if there is any way to get a expression as string and evaluate it as mathematical expression?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> 

void main {
 char expression[100];
 int answer;
 scanf("%s", &expression);
 // Let expression = "10+5"
 answer = expression
 printf("%d", answer);
 // Print 15
 getch();
}
```

Is there any libary or built-in function which can help me accomplish this task? I am using Turbo C++ 3.0.

---

P.S: I can't use modern compiler because it is included in our syllabus.

Comment: No there's no "library or built-in function" which does this. You have to build your own parser and evaluator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude this is in fact an answer already ;)

Comment: `scanf("%s", &expression);` is wrong because `expression` only holds 1 char. use `scanf("%99s", expression);` with `char expression[100];`

Comment: 1) This is not how strings work in C. 2) This is not valid C.

Comment: Lex (lexer generator) and Yacc (parser generator) are great for that purpose: http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/. Here is an example doing arithmetics like you want with Lex and Yacc: http://memphis.compilertools.net/interpreter.html

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am relatively new to this, so if can direct me to some tutorial or sample code or something similar

Comment: code is still wrong, `expression` would evaluate as a pointer to the first element of the array (type `char *`, so what `scanf()` wants), but `&expression` is a *pointer to the array* (type `char (*)[100]`). Also wrong because of a possible buffer overflow, you need to use `%99s` to prevent writing out of bounds of `expression`.

Comment: Further you mixed C and C++ in your question (title: C; text: C++; tag: C). Choose one!

Comment: @AndreKampling I guess "*Turbo C++*" as a product comes with a C compiler .... anything about this question clearly *attempts to be* C ;)

Comment: Do a Google search on "build an expression parser in C". You'll find lots of hits to give you some ideas. At a high level, you first need to decide for yourself: what do valid expressions look like? What operations? How complicated? I voted to close this question on the bases of looking for offline resources, but it is also too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

`answer = expression` makes no sense. If you intend `answer = find_answer(expression)`, and this function `find_answer()` is what you really want to know if exists, the answer remains "No.", there is no math-string parser built in to C. You can write it yourself, it's not super hard if you make it simple (only basic operators and two operands, for a start).

---

EDIT: Question had bug that was fixed, removed parts of answer.

Comment: simpler: use an array like `char expression[1024];` and then read with `fgets(expression, 1024, stdin)` (or, not-so-ideal-but-possible `scanf("%1023s", expression)`)

Comment: Oh and `readline()` isn't standard C, so as long as the question doesn't mention an implementation where it's available, this needs a disclaimer :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks :)

Comment: In my included syllabus book the syntax for declaring the code is like this and the code compiles just fine in Turbo. So is it better code or change in standard?

Comment: Then you should tag your question with Turbo and C++ instead of `c` and `string`. The answers you are getting are one a general level. I have not heard about *Turbo* before and do not know how it works, if the code you have in your question runs in Turbo it is quite a way away from `c`...

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset regarding edit: what **bug**? I don't remember seeing any wrong code here ...

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset Turbo C++ is a C/C++ compiler for DOS by Borland International released in 1991

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset Sorry if you didn't like my edit, but I liked your "*No.*" so much that I couldn't resist.

Comment: @FelixPalmen originally question said (as comments on question point to), `char expression` with no buffer size.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I think your edit was removed because I edited it also.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset yes, and questions are supposed to not change anything that invalidates answers. The correct thing to do would be to roll back the offending edit on the question, not to delete the major part of your answer.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset in regards to your edited answer, I had built a function that can perform such operation but need a parameter to know what operator is being used. I want to ask is that is there any way to read  '+'  inside the string and perform some action?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes that was a mistake on my behalf that my program had such a problem but I am relatively new to stackoverflow as well, so my question is code in the question can't be modified if a mistake a bit irrelevant to question is edited?

Comment: Inside this function you need to parse the string and find the operator and then use that operator on the operands...? Like `if(operator == '+') {` and so on, right? If you don't understand what to do you can either write a more specific question, or read online or in a book and find the answers there.

Comment: @UbadahJ of course you can correct a mistake in your code, **unless** there's already an answer referring to *exactly that mistake*. The general rule is just: don't change anything in your question that renders existing answers invalid or makes them confusing :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks and I will avoid such things.

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset should I ask a new question referring to this current situation? The code you described is exactly what I want to do in my own function.

Comment: @UbadahJ You should look around stackoverflow, other websites and possibly your syllabus for the answer you need before asking (if you can't find the answer yourself).

Comment: @HansPetterTaugbølKragset Actually this task is way out of my syllabus because it doesn't even includes array and string manipulations. Anyway I would look further for this problem.